# python sqlite3 record is not inserting into the database with a placeholder function

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, row, sql-insert

this code is not inserting my list(self.list2) into the database 'main.db'.  I read the the following posts already and they all seem to use the idea of using join() to create # of place holders based on the length of the list.

[Dynamically creating a placeholder to insert many column values for a row in SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374043/dynamically-creating-a-placeholder-to-insert-many-column-values-for-a-row-in-sql)

[Inserting to sqlite dynamically with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788403/inserting-to-sqlite-dynamically-with-python-3)

1. the code is running without errors.
2. I tested the code by printing

   ```
   return (f"{', '.join('?' * len(input))}")
   ```

   and it prints "?, ?, ?, ? ", so I know the function works.
3. the database is created properly with the following code:

   ```
   self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main
                       (T_num text  Primary Key NOT NULL,
                       Name text NOT NULL,
                       Item1 text,
                       Item2 text,
                       Item3 text)''')
   ```

Maybe I missed a small detail, or I don't know how the return statement/function works.
Please help me to trouble shoot this.  Thank you for any assistance.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


class Model():
    def __init__(self):

        self.list1 = [('Table #', '6'), ('Name', 'Jenn'), ('Beef 
               Tacos', '6'), ("Fish Tacos", "6")]
        self.list2 = list(map(": ".join, self.list1))

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("4th.db")
        self.cursor=self.conn.cursor()


        self.place_holder(self.list2)

    def place_holder(self, input):
        return (f"{', '.join('?' * len(input))}")

        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO main VALUES (place_holder(input))", self.list2)

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        c = Model()
```

Comment: In you `place_holder` function you returning before you executing did you noticed?
`return (f"{', '.join('?' * len(input))}")`. I think this line will go to the end of the function?

Comment: @zxy, hi, do you mean put the "return (f"{', '.join('?' * len(input))}")" line after "self.conn.close()"?  I tried, and it still not inserting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was trying to insert into db after `return` in your `place_holder` method which is not possible because the function exit after return. Also in your `sql` specify in which column you want to insert into.
like this

```
self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main (T_num, Name, Item1, Item2) VALUES {_placeholder}", self.list2)
```

There is your complete program, hope this will help you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


class Model():
    def __init__(self):

        self.list1 = [('Table #', '6'), ('Name', 'Jenn'), ('Beef Tacos', '6'), ("Fish Tacos", "6")]
        self.list2 = list(map(": ".join, self.list1))

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("4th.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        _placeholder = self.place_holder(self.list2)
        # specify here in which column you want to insert the data
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main (T_num, Name, Item1, Item2) VALUES {_placeholder}", self.list2)

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def place_holder(self, input_list):
        '''Returns the place holder (?, ?, .....) as string'''
        return f"({', '.join('?' * len(input_list))})"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Model()
```

Comment: hi @zxy thanks for your time to help me.  I was definitely confused because I didn't know i had to create a variable, and where to put it.  Lot more clear for me now.  One last question, the {_placeholder}, why is it a "{ }", instead of "( )"?  is it because of my f string return statement?  thanks again.

Comment: The `place_holder` method is returning `(?, ?, .....)` as string so yes `{}` for the f-strings.